# mod_rewrite problem, with accessing files?

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have this file that is on the root folder called sumbit.php

and when i acesss a page like this for exmaple

```
 http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?topic=14
```

the new url is

```
http://www.example.com/topic/14
```

on firebug its saying its accessing `http://www.example.co.uk/topic/submit.php`, when its meant to access `http://www.example.co.uk/submit.php`

my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /viewprofile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]*)$ /viewtopic.php?topic=$1 [L]
```

i dont seem to see what the problem is, p.s. the sumibit.php is from a form submit action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because the link to submit.php in your HTML is using relative paths. Relative paths depend on which directory you're currently in. So when you add slashes to your URL, it gets all messed up.

You should fix your HTML to use absolute paths (`/submit.php`). If this is not possible, write a new rewrite rule that will map `^.*/submit.php$` to the correct path.

Comment: so i need to do that rewrite rule for all the files

Comment: @getaway Just add `RewriteRule ^.*/submit.php$ /submit.php [L]` to your .htaccess file. Or you can hunt down all relative paths and fix each of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread I know, but... I think what the user (OP) was after was actual address cloaking.. / cloning... to hide the original path?...

So:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#my url is in the form of domain.com/photograph/GALLERY/IMAGE NUMBER
RewriteRule ^photograph/(.*)/(.*)$  /albums/index.php?op=large&gallery=$1&curImage=$2&rd=ht [QSA,L]
```